# Why alertmanager not sending sms

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I am using alert-manager and Prometheus to monitor my stack.

When I configure sending mails via alert-manager it works fine but when I configure to send sms via webhook it fails.

I added debug flag to alert-manager to verify it is getting the alerts and indeed the alerts are coming but till no sms are sent.

I also checked the webhook separately and it works perfectly.

Config file is:

```
global:
    resolve_timeout: '5m'
    smtp_smarthost: 'smtp.office365.com:587'
    smtp_from: 'no-reply@example.com'
    smtp_auth_username: 'no-reply@example.com'
    smtp_auth_password: 'xxxxx'
    smtp_require_tls: true


route:
  group_by: ['instance', 'severity']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 3h
  receiver: team-1

receivers:
  - name: 'team-1'
    webhook_configs:
      - send_resolved: true
        http_config: {}
        #max_alerts: 0      
        url: 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?from=example&text=test&to=xxxxxxxxxxxx&api_key=xxxxxxx&api_secret=xxxxxxx'
    email_configs:
      - to: 'john.doe@example.com'
```

I tried putting only mails and it works , tried only sms and it oes not work.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the API correctly?  I checked https://developer.vonage.com/api/sms?theme=dark and it seems to expect the parameters in the body.

Comment: In this case, the API isn't compatible with AlertManager. 
You probably would need to implement your own webhook which will translate the AM request to the API's format

Comment: They indeed recommend to use it in the body but I tried and it also works using parameters. even if the api call is incorrect I would expect to see the api call in the alertmanager logs which does not happen which makes me think it is not sending the api call at all

Comment: Are you monitoring alertmanager metrics? such as number of notification sent?

Comment: nope , did not think of monitoring it

Answer (score 0):

Eventually , I wrote a sms 'proxy' that will get a simple url get invocation and internally will call nexmo.

It did not work any other way.